# Outlook add-ins bugged in OWA (all browsers)

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

It looks like that some errors prevent add-ins to display their content in the task pane with OWA.

For example when trying to open Outlook Customer manager in OWA with Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). The javascript code is not executed, same thing happens with all add-ins.

[image]

Comment: Could you try the same in an inprivate session for chrome. Is Chrome the only browser you see this on or on IE/Firefox/Safari as well?

Comment: Same with Firefox and Edge. Same for colleagues. Can't you reproduce ?

Comment: We can't on the recent versions of OWA, could you share your OWA version number...

Comment: I sent a full console extract to andrew salamatov. We are using Office365 so I don't think we have a different OWA versions than others.

Comment: I cannot reproduce anymore... I will keep you posted if it happens again